# Checking for syllables, python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, dictionary, key

So I am trying to write the code that will do the following:

```
r""" (list of str, poetry pattern, pronunciation dictionary) -> list of str

Precondition: len(poem_lines) == len(pattern[0])

Return a list of lines from poem_lines that do not have the right number of
syllables for the poetry pattern according to the pronunciation dictionary.
If all lines have the right number of syllables, return the empty list.

>>> poem_lines = ['The first line leads off,', 'With a gap before the next.', 'Then the poem ends.']
>>> pattern = ([5, 5, 4], ['*', '*', '*'])
>>> word_to_phonemes = {'NEXT': ['N', 'EH1', 'K', 'S', 'T'],
...                     'GAP': ['G', 'AE1', 'P'],
...                     'BEFORE': ['B', 'IH0', 'F', 'AO1', 'R'],
...                     'LEADS': ['L', 'IY1', 'D', 'Z'],
...                     'WITH': ['W', 'IH1', 'DH'],
...                     'LINE': ['L', 'AY1', 'N'],
...                     'THEN': ['DH', 'EH1', 'N'],
...                     'THE': ['DH', 'AH0'], 
...                     'A': ['AH0'], 
...                     'FIRST': ['F', 'ER1', 'S', 'T'], 
...                     'ENDS': ['EH1', 'N', 'D', 'Z'],
...                     'POEM': ['P', 'OW1', 'AH0', 'M'],
...                     'OFF': ['AO1', 'F']}
>>> check_syllables(poem_lines, pattern, word_to_phonemes)
['With a gap before the next.', 'Then the poem ends.']
>>> poem_lines = ['The first line leads off,']
>>> check_syllables(poem_lines, ([0], ['*']), word_to_phonemes)
[]
"""
```

I do not understand how exactly it suppose to work, since every string in list has more syllables than it is given. ex: the first has 7 syllables but the pattern is 5, the second has 8 but 5 is given again, and so on.

I have no clear idea what to start with and what my code should do, so far I have this:

```
def check_syllables(poem_lines, pattern, word_to_phonemes):
   if  len(poem_lines) == len(pattern[0]):
        for k in word_to_phonemes:
            for v in poem_lines:
                if k is in v:
                   k , v = v, k
```

Comment: What's the problem? Are you just asking us to write some code for you (if so, don't-- that's not what we're here for)?

Comment: I am asking to explain what exactly am I asked here for. So far this just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Seems to me like whoever set the task is asking you to write a function to find how many syllables a poem has. The note at the beginning of the code explains that. What are you confused with, more specifically?

Comment: Well the note says that there are 5 syllables in a pattern, while I do see 7 of them in the first string. Even if I translate all those words to the values in a dictionary it is still not 5 as I am given. That is what I am confused about. If someone can explain that part for me.

Comment: Alright, good! You're right, the poem and the given pattern doesn't match up (although not in the way you've said). I'm not sure of the reasoning behind this. Maybe the author of the pseudocode wrote it wrong, or can't count syllables?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how the question breaks down:

(1) the signature of the required function:

```
r""" (list of str, poetry pattern, pronunciation dictionary) -> list of str
```

(2) a guarantee about the structure of the inputs:

```
Precondition: len(poem_lines) == len(pattern[0])
```

(3) specification of the returm value:

```
Return a list of lines from poem_lines that do not have the right number of
syllables for the poetry pattern according to the pronunciation dictionary.
If all lines have the right number of syllables, return the empty list.
```

(4) sample input - first argument [list of str]:

```
>>> poem_lines = ['The first line leads off,', 'With a gap before the next.', 'Then the poem ends.']
```

(5) sample input - second argument [poetry pattern]:

```
>>> pattern = ([5, 5, 4], ['*', '*', '*'])
```

(6) sample input - third argument [pronunciation dictionary]:

```
>>> word_to_phonemes = {'NEXT': ['N', 'EH1', 'K', 'S', 'T'],
...                     'GAP': ['G', 'AE1', 'P'],
...                     'BEFORE': ['B', 'IH0', 'F', 'AO1', 'R'],
...                     'LEADS': ['L', 'IY1', 'D', 'Z'],
...                     'WITH': ['W', 'IH1', 'DH'],
...                     'LINE': ['L', 'AY1', 'N'],
...                     'THEN': ['DH', 'EH1', 'N'],
...                     'THE': ['DH', 'AH0'], 
...                     'A': ['AH0'], 
...                     'FIRST': ['F', 'ER1', 'S', 'T'], 
...                     'ENDS': ['EH1', 'N', 'D', 'Z'],
...                     'POEM': ['P', 'OW1', 'AH0', 'M'],
...                     'OFF': ['AO1', 'F']}
```

(7) first sample output - return value [list of str]:

```
>>> check_syllables(poem_lines, pattern, word_to_phonemes)
['With a gap before the next.', 'Then the poem ends.']
```

(8) second sample output - return value [list of str]:

```
>>> poem_lines = ['The first line leads off,']
>>> check_syllables(poem_lines, ([0], ['*']), word_to_phonemes)
[]
"""
```

The first sample output (7) shows the expected return value for input lines (5) which **do not match** the pattern (6). That is, the three input lines have the pattern `[5, 7, 5]`, which does not match the pattern `[5, 5, 4]` in the last two elements, and so the corresponding lines are returned by the function.

The second sample input (8) shows what the output should be when the input lines (5) **do** match the pattern (6) - i.e. an empty list should be returned.

**PS**:

It looks like there is a in error in (8). The sample code should probably be:

```
>>> check_syllables(poem_lines, ([5], ['*']), word_to_phonemes)
```